# Double as default datatype for real numbers

Tags: c++, type-conversion

When any real number say 10.10 is passed as argument to function, why is it always assumed to be double and not float ?

Edit : I know i can always use 10.10f if I want it to be float.
But what I want to know is that is there any "specific/precise" reason why is it assumed to be double ?

Comment: Because 10.10 is a double. When you pass 5 as argument to a function why is it always assumed to be int and not short?

Comment: If you want to be passed as a float, you can write `10.10f`.

Comment: The real question is, do you have any real reason to want to have `10.10` be something other than `double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a literal such as `10.10` is `double`. The equivalent `float` literal would be `10.10f` or `10.10F`. So if you pass `10.10` as *argument* to a function, then the argument is double. However, the function's *parameter* type is set in the function declaration:

```
void foo(float x); // parameter is float

foo(1.23); // double argument to function with float parameter
```

Any mismatch between parameter type and argument type will result either in an implicit conversion (with possible precision loss) or in a compiler error, if no conversion is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

> When any real number say 10.10 is passed as argument to function, why is it always assumed to be double and not float ?

Because the type of literal 10.10 is `double`.

If you always pass a double to a function, then the argument is "always assumed to be double".

> But what I want to know is that is there any "specific/precise" reason why is it assumed to be double ?

Because that is the syntax for a double literal.

If you take a look at the  [this page, describing the syntax of floating point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), you'll find that

> suffix, if present, is one of f, F, l, or L. The suffix determines the type of the floating-point literal:
>
> - **(no suffix) defines double**
> - f F defines float
> - l L defines long double

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

Precision of 'double' is greater than that of 'float' datatype. If you want to make it a float value, use it like

```
10.10f
```

This is will work for you.

Comment: The double quotes around the number make a huge difference.

Comment: but, the intention was to intensify the correct form. That's it

Comment: I have edited your answer to make it appear in code block, rather than wrapping it inside quotes.

Comment: Ya, thanks a lot. I wasn't knowing this as I'm new to this